3-point function CFT
How can I compute the three-point function $<\phi^{(h_i)}(z_i) \phi^{(h_j)}(z_j) \phi^{(h_k)}(z_k)> $ in CFT using this conformal transformation $f(\xi)=\frac{(z_j-z_i)}{(z_j-z_k)} \frac{(\xi - z_k)}{(\xi - z_i)} ?$
I want to write the generic 3-point function as factor dependent in $z_i$, $z_j$ and $z_k$ multiplied by the 3-point green function of the fields evaluated at $0,1,\infty$, which will define the structure constants $C_{ijk}$.
I have already tried to perform this calculation, but i am missing something since the exponents of $z_{ij} = z_i - z_j$ are messed up.
I hope you can help me. Thank you for your time

is this useful? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529563/226902

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it is not helping me at all because i want to show that a $\math{SL}(2,/math{C})$ transformation fixes completely the 3-point function. I know the N-point function must be invariant under translations, dilatations and special conformal transformations each and i can extract the generic form, but i am trying to use one single transformation. I think a single transformation (like the one in the main question) should be enough, but i am doing something wrong…
